# I want to create custom calendar so i used JTAppleCalendar and want to display date in collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdateformatter, jtapplecalendar

I want to create custom calendar so I used JTAppleCalendar for this I have taken one collection view and want to display date in collection view cell but it is not displaying what should be the solution for this?

CalendarViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.calendarView.calendarDataSource = self
        self.calendarView.calendarDelegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension CalendarViewController:JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate,JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource{

    func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
        formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

        let startdate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 01")!
        let enddate = formatter.date(from: "2017 12 31")!
        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startdate, endDate: enddate)
      // print(formatter.string(from: startdate))
        return parameters
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplay cell: JTAppleCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {

        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell

        cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text

        return cell
    }
}



CalendarCell.swift

import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar
class CalendarCell: JTAppleCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: you have to create xib to display date.

Comment: @Sabarinathan tried using xib also..still same problem

Comment: try below code hope its work

Comment: okay..i will try and let u know..thanks

Comment: Did you remember to put constraints on your UILabel for your date cell?

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile Yes constraints are also given..any other solution?

Comment: @Sabarinathan still same problem..i have created abd used xib suggested by you but problem is not resolved yet

Comment: @PoojaDeshmukh send me your sample project. patchthecode@gmail.com
Or double check to see if you have followed the video tutorials fully

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile mail sent please check

Comment: @PoojaDeshmukh can you send the zipped copy of the whole project? The file looks ok. I believe your issue in in interface builder.

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile sorry don't have authority to send whole code..any other solution to solve issue?

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile i tried to print cell.daeLlabel.text dates on console and it is printing successfully..but not displaying cells on simulator

Comment: @Sabarinathan  Go to Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture view heirachy. This will give you a lot of info about what is happening with your views....Followed these steps where all views are okay but label is not available on view hierarchy of simulator then how to resolve this?

Comment: @PoojaDeshmukh Ok. I will ask you again. Do you have constraints setup on the UILabel?

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile Yes..all constraints of UILabel are okay

Comment: the chat here is getting too long. Open an issue here -> https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues and we'll continue. Or message me here before i head to sleep -> https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar

Comment: issue submitted

Comment: @PoojaDeshmukh post your screenshot and xib file view

Comment: /Users/vijay/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-10-26 at 2.43.56 PM.png

Answer (score 2):

```
calendarView.registerCellViewXib(file: "CalendarDateCell")
calendarView.delegate = self
calendarView.dataSource = self
calendarView.direction = .horizontal
calendarView.selectDates([selectedDate])
calendarView.reloadData()
```

add in viewdidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

[image]

your xib will be look like above image and take a outlet like below ignore arrow Img, Wrapper View

```
    import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class CalendarDateCell: JTAppleDayCellView {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var wrapperView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImg: UIImageView!
}
```